# Elastic Beanstalk CloudFormation integration with EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

In a CloudFormation template, I'm currently deploying a .NET app to Elastic Beanstalk, but would love to mount an EFS file system to it. I looked at this [.ebextensions config](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/blob/master/.ebextensions/aws_provided/instance%20configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config) file and included it in the project, like so:

```
~/my-app/
 |-- .ebextensions
 |   |-- storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config
```

Inside this .config file, it asks for the EFS Volume ID:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    EFS_VOLUME_ID: '`{"Ref" : "FileSystem"}`'
    EFS_MOUNT_DIR: '/efs_volume'
```

My question is that in the CloudFormation template, I want to try and pass the EFS ID as a parameter string called "FileSystem". Is it possible for the config files in the .ebextension directory of the app to have access to that parameter so I don't have to manually insert the EFS ID in the config file. In other words, have the { Ref: FileSystem} work accordingly?

Thanks for any help or clarification on this.

Comment: A .NET app, I assume, means a Windows Server... which [isn't yet supported](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/faq/#general) with EFS... is it?  The [.ebextensions config file](https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-docs/blob/master/.ebextensions/aws_provided/instance%20configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config) seems distinctly Amazon Linux-flavored, too, but I willingly concede that I may be talking utter nonsense, working from a flawed assumption about the OS involved, here.  Does this configuration currently work for you, at all?

Comment: I haven't actually tested it yet, but will update this thread when I do. You make a really good obvious point though. Just looked it up and saw "Using Amazon EFS with Microsoft Windows Amazon EC2 instances is not supported." Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html

Comment: Of course, "is not supported" does not necessarily mean "will not work."  Using EFS from machines outside your VPC, including not only Linux but also Solaris, is also "not supported," but I managed to find a way to [make that happen](http://serverfault.com/a/799213/153161).  Still, it seems like for now you may not be able to do this without at least some creativity and/or ingenuity, which would tend to exclude built-in CloudFormation support.

Answer (score 0):

AWS::EFS::FileSystem - AWS CloudFormation syntax for EFS.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-efs-filesystem.html
You can add EFS ID with key/value pair.